# JQuery run double request to route

Tags: javascript, jquery, request

when the page is fresh loaded and i click on my button. Everything works fine and jquery sends one request via route. When I click directly on the same button, without refreshing this page, jquery send two requests via route and my page is "freezed" and I cannot click on anything. What's wrong with my code? Any Idea?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var groupName = '';
    var groupid = '';

    $(".grp").click(function() {
        $('.text-danger').html('');
        groupName = $(this).data('groupname');
        groupid = $(this).attr('id');
        $('.text').html(groupName);
        $('#dataModal').modal({
            show: true
        });

        jQuery(".grpval").click(function(e){
           e.preventDefault();
           jQuery.ajaxSetup({
                headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
          });
           jQuery.ajax({
              url: "{{ route('request_group') }}",
              method: 'post',
              data: {
                'Gruppe': groupid
              },
              success: function(data){
                        if(typeof data.successsuccess != 'undefined'){
                            jQuery('.alert-success').show();
                            jQuery('.alert-success').html('<p>'+data.successsuccess+'</p>');
                            $('#dataModal').modal('toggle');
                            window.scrollTo(500, 0);
                        }else if(typeof data.successdberror != 'undefined'){
                            jQuery('.alert-danger').show();
                            jQuery('.alert-danger').html('<p>'+data.successdberror+'</p>');
                            $('#dataModal').modal('toggle');
                            window.scrollTo(500, 0);
                        }else{
                            jQuery.each(data.errors, function(key, value){
                                jQuery('.alert-danger').show();
                                jQuery('.alert-danger').html('<p>'+value+'</p>');
                                $('#dataModal').modal('toggle');
                                window.scrollTo(500, 0);
                            });
                        }  
                  }
              });
           });
    });
});
```

Comment: That's because you are assigning another click handler to an element when you click on `.grp` again

Comment: Don't create event listeners inside other event handlers. Move `jQuery(".grpval").click` out of `$(".grp").click`